# PHP script (include) not working from command line

Tags: php

I have a php script that works perfectly fine when run by the web server but when I run the script from the command line (or as a cron job) then it fails to find the file. The code that errors out is:

```
include('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
```

I tried including **DIR** but that does not work either

```
include(__DIR__ .'fpdf181/fpdf.php');
```

Can someone tell me how to include files for a script that will run from the command line

Comment: It&amp;#39;s running from another directory. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616158/running-cronjob-from-a-specific-directory . You could debug it using `getcwd()` method and saving the result in a file, this way you can know what's goin on.

Comment: As `__DIR__` does not include a trailing `/` - you may need `__DIR__ .'/fpdf181/...`.  I would also recommend using `require_once` instead of `include` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once

Comment: From the manual: "Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error. "  However a simple test on my setup, seems to favour the calling cwd first.  In short, without an explicit path, this is somewhat difficult to determine!

Comment: Which server do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

can you see this ([PHP Cron Job: Including file not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140675/php-cron-job-including-file-not-working))

as the link, you use "require" and not include

Code:
require('./fpdf181/fpdf.php')

happy codeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full path to the file (independent of current directory / env).

```
include('/path/to/lib/fpdf181/fpdf.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute my script by doing a cwd on the directory and going to the folder where the script was placed